# yii2 radiolist with angular js

Tags: angularjs, yii2

I want to know that  following is the code and I am not able to get value of that radio list in `angular js`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'value')->radioList($dropdown, ['class'=>'list-unstyled additional-radios', 'ng-model'=>'search.value']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is done  following way

field($model, 'value')->radioList($list, ['itemOptions' => ['class' =>'list-unstyled additional-radios',  'ng-model'=>'search.value']]); ?>